# How to level an existing wall

Tags: drywall, kitchens

We are about to replace our countertops in the kitchen & put a new backsplash up. The cabinets will remain. We have found the wall is unleveled. The area from the top of the countertop that is supposed to touch the wall there is a gap. How can I put up a backsplash on the existing Sheetrock without cutting the Sheetrock out.

Comment: What kind of counters? Is the backsplash integrated with the countertop? And can you describe in detail the "out of level"? (ie, what size of gap, and where exactly is it?)

Comment: A picture of the area and the gap would be helpful too

Comment: Countertops are typically custom measured and cut to fit the wall. Walls are rarely perfectly flat, so without a custom cut countertop, you'll always have a gap, no matter how level they are.

Comment: It's not clear to me how the wall is faulty. Please edit your question to explain better. "Level" means parallel to the horizon; "plumb" means vertical. Do you have either of those issues, or is it that the wall is bowed or wavy?

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes the countertop doesn't have an integral (pre-formed) back splash.

In order to move the countertop back to have the entire edge touching the wall you will need to scribe a line.

To scribe a cut line you must first get a scribe. This is nothing more than a compass, but one leg has a holder for a pencil ( the other leg is pointed).

To use it first orient the countertop so it is square to the cabinet bottoms. Depending where the gap(s) are located you must now find the space furthest from the back edge. This is the distance to set the compass too (the space between the pencil and the pointed leg). Tighten the nut so it remains at this setting.

Be certain to secure the countertop so it doesn't move (clamps or screws). Next, with the pointed leg against the wall and the penciled leg on the countertop angle the compass slightly(so you are pulling it) and pull it from one side of the countertop to the other. Keep both legs against their respective surface.

If all has gone well you should see a pencil line that tapers when compared to the back edge of the countertop. This is your cut line. Removing it will allow the countertop to fully contact the wall.

***Check This First*** If you have a countertop that has a lip or bull-nosed front edge be sure the amount that you need to remove isn't so much that the lip prevents it from touching the wall.